# How to do OpenScap Remediation process on windows 10 &11?

Tags: security

We are unable to continue remediation process on windows 10 and 11, Getting exited from command prompt once remediation process starts.

Issue : Getting exited once remediation starts with the message '-- Starting Remediation --'.

OpenScap Version used : 1.3.0 & 1.3.7

Attached screenshot for reference.

[Remediation error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKjAN.png)

Tried : vulnerability scan and remediation for windows 10 and 11.

Expected : Scan and remediation should be successful.

Current : Only scan is successful but remedition process is getting exited.

Could any one guide me about how to do remediation on windows 10 & 11 using openscap tool ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is quite unrelated to software development. Ask the vendor.